# RewriteRule with subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a virtual subdomain and want to point it to the www with a proxy rule. I try those rules but it doesn't work like this exemple :

http://news.domain.com/somestuff => http://www.domain.com/somestuff

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.[NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^news\.domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

Any ideas where i made an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code :

```
 ServerAlias news.domain.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.domain.com$
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.domain.com/$1 [P]
```